# how to bind html in to panel in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, c#-4.0

I have html content in my data base and want bind this html into panel or div.

I want get this html content into data base and put in to  panel and than after i want to find control of html.

My html content have some textbox,lable,button some image control so i want to find this control

If posible thann give me solution.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use an asp.net literal and place the html in the literal in the code behind. The html will need to be pulled from the database in some way. If you need help doing that let me know.

**Front End**

```
<asp:Literal ID="litTest" runat="server" Text=""/>
```

**Code Behind**

```
litTest.Text = "*Whatever your html content would be*";
```

*If you use an asp.net literal you can then use the following mode properties:*

**PassThrough**

- The contents of the control are not modified.

**Encode**

- The contents of the control are converted to an HTML-encoded string.

**Transform**

- Unsupported markup-language elements are removed from the contents of
  the control. If the Literal control is rendered on a browser that
  supports HTML or XHTML, the control's contents are not modified.

Comment: ok thanks now i want find control from literlal control so how can i find it

Answer (score 1):

Make the panel or div server accessible but adding id and runat

**Html**

```
<div id="div1" runat="server></div>
```

**Code behind**

```
div1.InnerHTML = "yourhtmlstring";
```

**or**

```
div1.InnerHTML = yourhtmlstringvariable;
```

To find the control in the server control suppose after assigning html to div1 you can use **[FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx)** method. I assume there is control in div1 html with id TextBox1.

```
 TextBox myControl1 = (TextBox) div1.FindControl("TextBox1");
```

Comment: thanks now how to find control in my html content

Comment: You can use FindControl method of control to find controls within it, I updated my answer as well. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx

Comment: thanks again but problem is i have so many control in html so how can i decide this text box or this is lable?

Comment: Actually i want to apply dynemic style in my control.so how can i decide which type controll is there/